# Send command to service from C++

Tags: c++, windows-services, servicecontroller

how can I send command to a Windows service from C++? Equivalent .NET code is:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService");
sc.ExecuteCommand(255);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From native C++, you will need to:

1. Open a handle to the service control manager,
2. Use the service control manager to obtain a service handle for the service you want to control,
3. Send a control code or codes to the service, and
4. Close the handles opened in steps 1 and 2.

For example, this code restarts the time synchronization service.  First, I create a wrapper class for the service handles, to close them automatically when leaving the block.

```
class CSC_HANDLE
{
public:
 CSC_HANDLE(SC_HANDLE h) : m_h(h) { }
 ~CSC_HANDLE() { ::CloseServiceHandle(m_h); }
 operator SC_HANDLE () { return m_h; }
private:
 SC_HANDLE m_h;
};
```

Then, I open the service control manager (using [OpenSCManager()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323(VS.85).aspx)) and the service I want to control.  Note that the dwDesiredAccess parameter to [OpenService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330(VS.85).aspx) must include permissions for each control I want to send, or the relevant control functions will fail.

```
BOOL RestartTimeService()
{
    CSC_HANDLE hSCM(::OpenSCManager(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, GENERIC_READ));
    if (NULL == hSCM) return FALSE;

    CSC_HANDLE hW32Time(::OpenService(hSCM, L"W32Time", SERVICE_START | SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS));
    if (NULL == hW32Time) return FALSE;
```

To stop the service, I use [ControlService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682108(VS.85).aspx) to send the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP code, and then check the return value to make sure the command succeeded.  If any error other than ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE is reported, I assume that starting the service is not going to succeed.

```
    SERVICE_STATUS ss = { 0 };
    ::SetLastError(0);
    BOOL success = ::ControlService(hW32Time, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss);
    if (!success)
    {
        DWORD le = ::GetLastError();
        switch (le)
        {
        case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
        case ERROR_DEPENDENT_SERVICES_RUNNING:
        case ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
        case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
        case ERROR_INVALID_SERVICE_CONTROL:
        case ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL:
        case ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT:
        case ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IN_PROGRESS:
            return FALSE;

        case ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE:
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

After instructing the service to stop, I wait for the service manager to report that the service is in fact stopped.  This code has two potential bugs, which you may wish to correct for production code:

1. Sleep(1000) will suspend the message loop on this thread, so you should use another method to delay execution if this function will run on a UI thread.  You can construct a suitable sleep-with-message-loop using [MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684245(VS.85).aspx).
2. The DWORD returned from [GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) will wrap around to zero eventually; if it wraps around while this function is waiting, the wait may give up sooner than I intended.

   ```
   DWORD waitstart(::GetTickCount());
   while (true)
   {
       ZeroMemory(&ss, sizeof(ss));
       ::QueryServiceStatus(hW32Time, &ss);
       if (SERVICE_STOPPED == ss.dwCurrentState) break;
       ::Sleep(1000);
       DWORD tick(::GetTickCount());
       if ((tick < waitstart) || (tick > (waitstart + 30000))) return FALSE;
   }
   ```

Finally, knowing that the service is in a stopped state, I call [StartService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686321(VS.85).aspx) run it again.

```
    success = ::StartService(hW32Time, 0, NULL);
    if (!success) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use [ControlService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682108%28VS.85%29.aspx), see [Service Control Requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685153%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little program which will connect to a service called "MYSERVICE" then send a command 141 (which is defined by the service)

```
// ServiceCommunicator.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SC_HANDLE managerHandle;
    SC_HANDLE serviceHandle;

    SERVICE_STATUS   controlParms;
    DWORD retStatus;

    managerHandle = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, GENERIC_READ);
    if (NULL != managerHandle)
    {
        serviceHandle = OpenService(managerHandle, L"MYSERVICE", SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);

        if (NULL != serviceHandle)
        {
            cout << "connected to Service" << endl;
            retStatus = ControlService(serviceHandle, 141, &controlParms);

            if (retStatus)
            {
                //Get the return code from the service
                cout << "For command 141, return code from service was " << controlParms.dwWin32ExitCode << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "Sending command 141 failed" << endl;

            CloseServiceHandle(serviceHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "could not connect to Service" << endl;
        }

        CloseServiceHandle(managerHandle);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "could not open service manager" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```